# Specific Game Proposals on Area 51

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, graduate-to-site

despite my interest [in an all WoW prop](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11065/world-of-warcraft) , I've noticed that since it sprouted up, the number of wow related questions have stagnated. Should the health of the general gaming site be considered with respect to these sites being up?

I doubt that any one game splintering off would keep gaming.se from getting used (and thus deleted), and it seems like if theres one single game site that would get off the ground it would be a WoW centered one; but is it a matter for concern if a bunch of games start splintering off?

Comment: There was a very similar discussion about stackoverflow.com and proposals that were focused on one topic that would be a tag on SO. The discussion was on meta, let me see if I can find a link.

Comment: Link ♪ http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244/should-world-of-warcraft-questions-be-closed

Comment: Thanks for link, it is more about making WoW users of gaming.se use Epic Advice instead, but the problem there for me is EpicAdvice.com is blocked by my work content filter and stackexchange isn't. I think the crux applies though, do we want a significant amount of community (who have knowledge about games other than WoW) go to another site and not contribute here?

Comment: Thanks @Grace, I actually meant a discussion about sites that overlapped with SO (like a C# proposal). Couldn't find the link though...

Comment: @Juan and mfg, I'm aware you two are not referring to the WOW situation specifically but for a general scenario. I just wanted to link it to show some of discussion that we've had on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

If we plan to be the SO of gaming, we need every game in here!

So if you have WoW questions, you should be asking them here.

Plus if it were up to me, I would let all the separate gaming sites life and just merge them into one big site. WoW is just the C# of gaming